# Exception occurred when trying to issue security tokenactivated

Tags: windows, sts, 2012

I have just completed an upgrade of one of our servers from Windows 2008 to Window 2012 running Sharepoint 2010.

Our sharepoint site works but we have run into an issue with the Search facility.  I have used the ULS view to track down the error to this:

> An exception occurred when trying to issue security token: The requested service, `http://localhost:32843/SecurityTokenServiceApplication/securitytoken.svc/actas`
>    could not be activated. See the server's diagnostic trace logs for more information.

Can anyone offer any assistance please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Search to work the securitytoken.svc should work . To troubleshoot this issues, it will be good to check if we can browse to the STS Web Service page.

To browse you have to go to IIS Manager --> Sites --> SharePoint WebServices --> SecurityTokenServiceApplication, click on 'Content View' down at the bottom, right click on Securitytoken.svc and click Browse. This service should work for search to work .

How to fix STS :
https://web.archive.org/web/20150206061252/http://blogs.technet.com/b/sykhad-msft/archive/2012/02/25/sharepoint-2010-nailing-the-error-quot-the-security-token-service-is-unavailable-quot.aspx

> Fix 1 Check if we can browse to the STS Web Service page. To browse
>   you have to go to IIS Manager --> Sites --> SharePoint WebServices -->
>   SecurityTokenServiceApplication, click on 'Content View' down at the
>   bottom, right click on Securitytoken.svc and click Browse (as shown
>   below)
>
> Fix 2 Right click on the SecurityTokenServiceApplication and click
>   Explore, copy the web.config and compare the file with an
>   out-of-the-box file with no modifications. Try replacing the file with
>   a fresh copy and resetting IIS (keep your original file, of course).
>
> Fix 3 Run the following commands one by one on SharePoint PowerShell:
>
> ```
> $h = Get-SPServiceHostconfig
> $h.Provision()
> $services = Get-SPServiceApplication
> foreach ($service in $services) { $service.provision();
> write-host $service.name}
> ```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work when I try and browse that service/url:   
Server Error in '/SecurityTokenServiceApplication' Application.

Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: certificate 
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

 Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: certificate

Comment: follow the blog to fix the issue .

Comment: Just struggling with the powershell part.  I've previousley tried the web.config swap with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the assistance.  The powershell stuff in the post fixed our issue.  We had tried the first bit, replacing the web.config, with no success.  The powershell commands have resolved everything and we are now able to search again.

Thanks

John